# How to extract data from webpage

Tags: html, vb.net, data-extraction

I access a webpage (eg "http://signal.eu.org/osm/#locs=40.853293,14.244461;41.312371,16.288605"), which shows a map control with details of a rail route. On that webpage there exists the map as a control. If I examine the map control using standard Edge functionality, I can see a series of coordinates. I would like to extract these coordinates for use in my VB.Net program. I can handle the desktop part, but the Webpage thing is all new to me. I have tried using a WebClient and downloading as a string, or using a WebBrowser and examining that object, but all I see is the main web page details and not the map control.

Any help would be really appreciated as I have just spent a few hours with google and I feel like I'm not really asking the right question.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it's not at all clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. Map as a control? standard Edge functionality? Examining that object? You need to be a lot clearer and more descriptive otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not specific enough, but I'm a bit unsure of the correct terminology. But if you go to the webpage and right click on the route and select 'inspect', a 'windows / edge' panel will appear on the right. If you inspect that panel, it will contain numbers that equate to the route on the map. I wish to access those numbers, I can then convert those numbers to geographic coordinates which I can then plot in my vb.net program. – many thanks for your interest/help

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you want the direction of the map. So you want the step by step direction of how to go from "Via Matteo Renato Imbriani, Quartieri Spagnoli, Municipalità 2, Napels, Napoli, Campania, 80136, Italië" to "strada  locale, Barletta, Barletta-Andria-Trani, Apulië, 76121, Italië"?

If this is the case, google provides an API exactly for that (Google for "Google direction API").

Comment: Babhoster: I do actually already use the google API, which I can use and works fine for roads. However this is for a railway. If I use the google API with Request.TravelMode = TravelModeOption.Transit, it returns a very limited set of coordinates (maybe 2 or 3 points). I wish to get from the exercise a list of coordinates that I can plot in my program. Eventual aim is to plan a railway route around Europe and then plot the coordinates of the route in my program. I don't actually need travel directions and just need the coordinates to be reasonably accurate. Many thanks for your help/interest.